# iOS Firebase OTP verification without Sign Up

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need help verifying the OTP with Firebase.
I Managed to receive a SMS with the OTP but when I verify it I get automatically signed up and I only know if the OTP was valid if I signed up - else I get a popup like "invalid otp".
How can I manually validate the otp? My goal is to open another screen where the user puts in more information.

```
func verifyCode(){
    let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: self.CODE, verificationCode: code)
    print(credential)
    loading = true
    //here i just want to verify my OTP without signing in...
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (result, err) in //here i am signing in...
        self.loading = false
        if let error = err{
            let generator = UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()
            generator.notificationOccurred(.error)
            self.code = ""
            self.errorMsg = error.localizedDescription
            withAnimation{ self.error.toggle()}
            return
        }
        self.gotoRegistration = true
        withAnimation{self.status = true}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to use Firebase Authentication's phone/OTP provider without automatically signing the user in.

But the fact that the user is signed in to Firebase, does not mean that you have to grant them access to all parts/data in your app. If you want them to provide more information, you can do so before or after signing them in to Firebase, and make it part of the same sign-up flow as far as the user is concerned.

So something like:

```
// Sign the user in with Firebase
  // Check if the user has provider the additional registration information
    // If not, send them to the registration information screen
    // If so, send them to the next screen of the app
```

You can also enforce these rules in your back-end code, or (if you use one of Firebase's back-end services) in the [server-side security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules).